# How does "oder auch nur" differ in meaning from "oder auch" or "oder nur"?

Tags: meaning

> Es gibt nichts, was er sagen könnte, was die Tatsache ändern **oder auch nur** rechtfertigen würde.

My assumption:

> = "There's nothing she could ever say that could change ***or even just*** justify the fact."

The thing is that I'm not sure if this is a set expression that native speakers often employ to introduce one of the least difficult things imaginable, as an example?

How does it compare to saying:

> Es gibt nichts, was er sagen könnte, was die Tatsache ändern **oder auch** rechtfertigen würde.
>
> {or}: Es gibt nichts, was er sagen könnte, was die Tatsache ändern **oder nur** rechtfertigen würde.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, let's first look at the semantics of your example sentence: Somebody has done something unforgiveable, and now his words can neither undo ("ändern"), nor justify ("rechtfertigen") his actions. Notice that these things are not equal in value: Undoing ("ändern") an action is *more* than merely justifying it ("rechtfertigen").

The phrase "oder auch nur" serves to express this difference in value. To understand why we need *all* of its parts, let's take a closer look at them individually:

---

### 1. oder

The conjunction **"oder" ("or")**, in its solitary form, expresses that there are two alternatives of *equal* value:

> Nächstes Silvester laden wir unsere Freunde ein **oder** feiern allein. (Was von beidem wir tun, ist mir egal.)
>   Coming New Year's Eve, we're going to invite all our friends **or** celebrate on our own. (I don't care which of the two we'll actually do.)"

For our purposes, however, a solitary "oder" won't do because our two alternatives *aren't* equal in value:

> <strike>Es gibt nichts, was er sagen könnte, was die Tatsache ändern **oder** rechtfertigen würde.</strike>
>   <strike>There's nothing he could say to change **or** justify the fact.</strike>

---

### 2. "nur"

To add this additional meaning, we need to add the adverb **"nur"** ("at least" in this context) to the sentence:

> Es gibt nichts, was er sagen könnte, was die Tatsache ändern **oder nur** rechtfertigen würde.
>   There's nothing he could say to change **or at least** justify the fact.

Note that this construction already expresses everything the speaker wishes to impart (i.e. that he deems "justifying" worth less than "undoing").

---

### 3. "auch"

However, if the speaker wishes to add a sense of frustration and disappointment to the sentence, the particle **"auch"** (here "even") will serve this purpose:

> Es gibt nichts, was er sagen könnte, was die Tatsache ändern **oder auch nur** rechtfertigen würde.
>   There's nothing he could say to change **or even at least** justify.

---

### 4. "oder auch?"

Lastly, let's take a look at the last construction you've mentioned in your example - the variant *without* the adverb "nur":

> <strike>Es gibt nichts, was er sagen könnte, was die Tatsache ändern *oder auch* rechtfertigen würde.</strike>

To my ears, this sentence does not work for two main reasons. Firstly, as mentioned above, the "or" makes it sound like "ändern" and "rechtfertigen" are equally valuable. Secondly, the "auch" even *strengthens* this impression. This is because the word "auch" can also be an adverb, meaning "as well".

---

### Conclusion

To sum up, every individual word has a part to play in the given construction. While some, such as "auch", are optional and *can* be added for emotional nuance, others (such as "nur") are obligatory because they narrow down the overall meaning to exactly what the speaker wishes to express.

Answer (score 2):

*... oder auch nur ...* can also be expressed by *... wenigstens ...*, which  maybe explains the difference better.

> Es gibt nichts, was er sagen könnte, was die Tatsache ändern oder auch rechtfertigen würde.

Simply translates to

> There's nothing he could say to change the fact or justify it.

*changing the fact* and *justifying it* are taken as somewhat equivalent, and non-exclusive alternatives here.

> Es gibt nichts, was er sagen könnte, was die Tatsache ändern oder auch nur rechtfertigen würde.
>
> Es gibt nichts, was er sagen könnte, was die Tatsache ändern oder wenigstens rechtfertigen würde.
>
> Es gibt nichts, was er sagen könnte, was die Tatsache ändern oder zumindest rechtfertigen würde.

Would translate to

> There's nothing he could say to change the fact or at least justify it.

*Changing the fact* and *justifying it* are **not** considered equivalent alternatives - the first one would be considered "better" than the latter, expressed by *auch nur*, *wenigstens* or *zumindest*. The phrase also somewhat implies the latter is considered one step on the way to the former.

Answer (score 1):

The second version

> Es gibt nichts, was er sagen könnte, was die Tatsache ändern **oder auch** rechtfertigen würde.

translates to

> There's nothing he could say, which would change or justify the fact.

Both options are equivalent alternatives. The `auch` emphasizes that the two options are non-exclusive.

---

The third

> Es gibt nichts, was er sagen könnte, was die Tatsache ändern **oder nur** rechtfertigen würde.

says, that the second option is worse and easier to achieve than the first, but not even that is possible (the first even less).

---

In the first version

> Es gibt nichts, was er sagen könnte, was die Tatsache ändern **oder auch nur** rechtfertigen würde.

The `auch nur` is a stronger version of `nur`, it emphasizes the difference between the two options (the second is way worse than the first) and also the unlikliness of it happening.